# Multiple find by xargs

Tags: find, xargs

I have a problem; 1) I'm using find command to find directories; 2) I need to execute another find command in previously found directories.
I'want something like this `find . -type d -not -name bad | xargs find {0} *`
Is it possible somehow to tell xargs where to put result of the previous command output {0}.

I found a solution by using -exec instead of xargs command:
`find . -type d -not -name bad -exec find {} -name '*' \;`

But I personally more like xargs, is it possible to do that thing with xargs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your requirement correctly, you might be better to do something more akin to:

```
find . -type d | grep -i <bad> | xargs -i find {} -type f
```

The pipe through `grep` is more personal preference - you could keep using the args to `find` to exclude the directories you aren't interested in.  The key thing here is the `-i` switch to `xargs` and the use of `{}` rather than `{0}`.

Comment: +1 for `xargs -i command {} params`

Answer (score 0):

`find` + `xargs` without using `-print0` can be dangerous. See why: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xargs#The_separator_problem

You may want to use GNU Parallel instead:

```
find . -type d | grep -i <bad> | parallel find {} -type f
```

Learn more: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OpaiGYxkSuQ